# SVG -> Google Drawing

Tags: python, google-app-engine, svg

I want to create SVG drawings for Google Drawings using Python, generating them in the browser and then uploading them into Google Docs. I see the Google Docs List API (3.0) supports importing files and then uploading them into entries with the ResumableUploader, but I was thinking of creating images in the browser with the svg-edit library. Does anyone know how to upload SVG drawings to google docs directly from the browser to Google Docs? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can. You just have to generate the right POST request. This can probably be done with Javascript. See: [How do you create a document in Google Docs programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704902/how-do-you-create-a-document-in-google-docs-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! My server code is in Python, so I'd prefer to not convert into Javascript. I've been working with google's [urlfetch.fetch](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/fetchfunction.html), but now I'm getting a 401 error. I'm using oauth2 for security so I'm sending the oauth token's access token to href = https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/drawing%{id}. Can you tell what the problem is from that, or what other information should I post? (the 500 character limit is curtailing me from putting up everything at once).