# How to upload a Google Docs document in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, google-docs-api

I want to create a Google Docs document from within Haskell, so basically I want to do in Haskell what this little C# program does (adapted from a Google sample program):

```
using Google.GData.Documents;
using Google.GData.Client;

namespace DocListUploader
{
    public class GDocConsole
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var user = "...";
            var passwd = "...";
            var file = "...";

            service = new DocumentsService("DocListUploader");
            service.setUserCredentials(user, passwd);
            service.UploadDocument(file, null);
        }
    }
}
```

From the Google Docs API description [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/)
 and this SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704902/how-do-you-create-a-document-in-google-docs-programmatically) I understood it's "only" a matter of sending a couple of HTTP POSTs and getting the OAuth authentification done, but just how? Has anybody already done it and has some code samples for me...?

EDIT: Still could not figure out how to use the oauth libraries, so I just wrote a little C# wrapper:

```
using Google.GData.Documents;
using Google.GData.Client;

public class GoogleDoc
{
    public static int Upload(string user, string passwd, string file)
    {
        try
        {
            var service = new DocumentsService("DocListUploader");
            service.setUserCredentials(user, passwd);
            service.UploadDocument(file, null);

            return 0;
        }
        catch
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

and called this wrapper from Haskell via hs-dotnet:

```
module Upload where

import NET

upload :: String -> String -> String -> IO (Int)
upload user passed file = 
   invokeStatic "[GoogleDoc.dll]GoogleDoc" "Upload" (user, passed, file)

testLocal :: IO ()
testLocal = do
  let user = "..."
  let passwd = "..."
  let file = "..."
  returnCode <- upload user passwd file
  putStrLn (show returnCode)
```

Comment: Although I'm not familiar with the Google Docs API, you should probably check out the [http package on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [haskell-oauth](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hoauth) library to do the oauth and to upload the documentation, like mentioned already, you can try the [http](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP) package from Haskell.

Comment: Thanks! I can't get haskell-oauth to run though, it seems like it's not so easy to install curl on Windows. There's also authenticate-oauth, which runs fine, but I can't figure out what I need to do in what order. An example would be great...

Comment: The factual-api package represents an example of usage for hoauth.
http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/factual-api/0.6.1/doc/html/src/Network-Factual-API.html