# How to create a Google Doc through the Google API

Tags: javascript, python, google-apps-script, google-api

I am developing a Google App Engine Python based Web application.
I need to automatically create a new document in a folder in the  Google Drive account of the currently logged user when he/she presses a button. 
I am trying to figure out what library to exploit. I am now using the Python Client Library 3.0 to manage the user's calendars but I can't see how to use them to create new docs and set up some initial content.
It would be great if I could use some Javascript library but I am a bit confused about the many different (sometime depcreated) documentation I find on the Internet (i.e. Google Apps Script, Google DocsList, etc.).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704902/how-do-you-create-a-document-in-google-docs-programmatically

Comment: the Google Documents List Api 3.0 (proposed in the answer of the question you have posted) are deprecated since 2012.

Comment: You can refer this https://developers.google.com/drive/web/integrate-create . But you will need a Drive UI. Although not sure how to do that but still this can be helpful

Comment: Thank you but it does not explain anything to me. I still can't find any reference about how to create a brand new document in Google Docs (Drive or whatever), with some custom sections in it

Comment: I found this example page: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#examples . 
You can create a doc just the way you want. Still no documentation!

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code to create Google doc using Google App Script, you can add text, html content and images.

```
//Create document in google drive with given name, open the document and returns doc object
doc = DocumentApp.create('digest.doc');

//Get the document body
var body = doc.getBody();

//Insert some text into body
var text = body.editAsText();

text.insertText(0, 'This is sample text...\n');
```

You can refer [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/) link for API documentation.