# Creating or Copying Google documents with Net::Google::Spreadsheets

Tags: perl, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

Is it possible to use the API to create, rename and copy Google documents before I write to them?

So far I'm able only to write to existing documents, using [`Net::Google::Spreadsheets`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Google::Spreadsheets).

Comment: I don't think you can do it with Net::Google::Spreadsheets, but see [How do you create a document in Google Docs programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704902/how-do-you-create-a-document-in-google-docs-programmatically)