# Programmatic access to Google Docs

Tags: google-docs-api

I have a need to generate and share Google Docs programatically. In this case, these are reports generated weekly from various sources like JIRA and a number of other tools used internally at our company.

The only documentation found so far seems to be related to use of Google scripts to generate documents.

Is there something similar to gspread for Google Spreadsheets that works with Google Docs? A python wrapper would enable us to collect the data from various sources and do some analysis before populating the report.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704902/how-do-you-create-a-document-in-google-docs-programmatically). It suggested that you need to create a blob of data representing your document in any of the formats listed [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-open#open_and_convert_google_docs_in_your_app), depending on your programming language, simplest may be `text/csv` for a spreadsheet and `application/rtf` for a text-document. Then put in in an appropriately formatted `POST` data. You can also check the sample [python code](https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client) in the given link.