# How do I rename a file to google drive rest api? Retrofit2

Tags: android, rest, request, rename, retrofit2

In the Google documentation about it is not written, I use retrofit 2. Help. Write what request should be sent and what parameters to transmit

**interface:**

```
 @PATCH("drive/v3/files/{fileId}")
    @Multipart
    Call<ResponseBody> renameFileGoogle(
            @Path("fileId")String fileId, 
            @Part MultipartBody.Part metaPart
    );
```

**call metod:**

```
public void renameMetod(String id, String title) {
    String content = "{\"name\": \"" + title + "\"}";
  MediaType contentType = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    MultipartBody.Part metaPart = MultipartBody.Part.create(RequestBody.create(contentType, content));
    Call<ResponseBody> renameRequest = server.renameFileGoogle(id, metaPart);
    renameRequest.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>()...
```

Comment: request code=400

Comment: This is not a multipart request. And have you implemented OAuth in your app? Why aren't you using Google Drive Android Api. I think it is the better way to do it https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's there in the documentation https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/patch

You need to send an HTTP PATCH request

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{fileId}

RequestBody:
{"title":"newTitle"}
```

For version 3
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}
RequestBody:
{"name":"newTitle"}
```

Comment: Use v3 Rest api(