# Android Rename File using Google Drive REST API v3?

Tags: java, android, rest, google-drive-api, rename

How do I rename a file using the Google Drive REST API on Android? I have searched the internet however I could, but I can't find how to do this.

I am trying to write a sync method that moves and renames the cloud files if it detects that the local copy has been moved or renamed:

```
void syncMetadataOnly (com.google.api.services.drive.model.File cloud, 
                       java.io.File local) throws IOException { 
    Workspace.FINF fileInfo = Workspace.getFileInfo (this, local); // Just my metadata object. 
    Map<String, String> appProperties = cloud.getAppProperties (); 
    // We keep track of the last rename and move in our private app properties: 
    long cloudLastRename = appProperties.containsKey ("last-rename") ? 
                                   Long.valueOf (appProperties.get ("last-rename")) : 0; 
    long cloudLastMove = appProperties.containsKey ("last-move") ? 
                                 Long.valueOf (appProperties.get ("last-move")) : 0; 
    boolean needUpdate = false; 
    boolean needName = false; 
    boolean needMove = false; 
    if (fileInfo.lastRename > cloudLastRename) { 
        // The file was renamed locally since the last sync. 
        needName = true; 
        needUpdate = true; 
    } else fileInfo.title = cloud.getName (); 
    String oldRecognizedParent = null; 
    if (fileInfo.lastMove > cloudLastMove) { 
        // The file was moved to a different folder locally since the last sync. 
        oldRecognizedParent = getFirstKnownParentId (cloud); // May be null, if not found. 
        needMove = true; 
        needUpdate = true; 
    } 
    if (needUpdate) { 
        cloud.setAppProperties (appProperties); 
        Drive.Files.Update update = mDriveService.files ().update (fileInfo.driveResourceId, null); 
        if (needName) update.set /// How do I rename the file? 
        if (needMove) { 
            if (oldRecognizedParent != null) 
                update.setRemoveParents (oldRecognizedParent); 
            update.setAddParents (fileInfo.driveParentId); // Set to the NEW parent's ID. 
        }
        com.google.api.services.drive.model.File result = update.execute (); 
    } 
}
```

The closest answer I have found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705453/how-do-i-rename-a-file-to-google-drive-rest-api-retrofit2), but do I really have to use raw HTTP for this?

Comment: Try checking this out, [edit contents](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/EditContentsActivity.java) and [edit metadata](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/EditMetadataActivity.java) from the [Google Drive Android API Demos](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos). You can use the Google Drive Android API and not rely on the REST API. Hope this helps.

Comment: That's what I would prefer to do. But the DriveApi doesn't allow the DRIVE scope - only FILE and APP_FOLDER. I want to use an app folder that the user can add things to themselves, but APP_FOLDER scope is invisible to the user, while FILE scope doesn't allow my app to see files that the user dragged into my app folder. That's why I switched to REST.