# Generating Google Docs from AngularJS & Cloudant

Tags: angularjs, json, couchdb, google-docs, cloudant

I'm planning on generating a contract and invoice (populating a template with the data from either the AngularJS object or the new Cloudant object) when a user registers him/herself through an AngularJS app.

I've not been able to find an example of such thing using Google Docs.

Any comment on if this would be even possible?

Answer (score 1):

i havent tried it but expect it would be possible. you should be able to take the data from either Cloudant or directly from the form users fill out and upload it using the Google API

- https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#basic_uploads
- https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2704986