# Using Python, how can I read plain text from a Google Doc?

Tags: python, download, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am attempting to read the raw text/content of a Google Doc (just a plain document, not a spreadsheet or presentation) from within a Python script, but so far have had little success.

Here's what I've tried:

```
import gdata.docs.service
client = gdata.docs.service.DocsService()
client.ClientLogin('email', 'password')
q = gdata.docs.service.DocumentQuery()
q.AddNamedFolder('email', 'Folder Name')
feed = client.Query(q.ToUri())
doc = feed.entry[0] # extract one of the documents
```

However, this variable doc, which is of type gdata.docs.DocumentListEntry, doesn't seem to contain any content, just meta information about the document.

Am I doing something wrong here? Can somebody point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DocumentQuery` doesn't return you all the documents with their contents—that would take forever. It just returns a list of documents, with metadata about each. (Actually, IIRC you can get a preview page this way, so if your document is only one page that might be enough…)

You then need to download the content in a separate request. The `content` element has a `type` (the MIME type) and a `src` (the URL to the actual data). You can just download that `src`, and parse it. However, you can override the default type by adding an `exportFormat` parameter, so you don't need to do any parsing.

See the section [**Downloading documents and files**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#downloading_documents_and_files) in the docs, which has an example showing how to download a document and specify a format. (It's in .NET rather than Python, and it uses HTML rather than plain text, but you should be able to figure it out.)

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE (Mar 2019)** Good news! The [Google Docs REST API](https://developers.google.com/docs) is now available. More info about it from [my SO answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42522473/305689), but to get you going, here's the [official Python "quickstart" sample](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python) showing you how to get the title of a Google Doc in plain text.

Both the Apps Script and Drive REST API solutions originally answered below are still valid and are alternate ways to get the contents of a Google Doc. (The Drive API works on both Python 2 & 3, but Apps Script is JavaScript-only.)

**Bottom-line**: if you want to download the entire Doc in plain text, the Drive API solution is best. If you want to programmatically CRUD different parts of a Doc, then you *must* use either the Docs API or Apps Script.

**(Feb 2017)** The code in the OP and the only other answer are both now out-of-date as [ClientLogin authentication was deprecated](https://developers.googleblog.com/2012/04/changes-to-deprecation-policies-and-api.html) back in 2012(!), and [GData APIs](http://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/directory) are the previous generation of Google APIs. While not all GData APIs have been deprecated, [all **newer** Google APIs](http://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis) do **not** use [the Google Data protocol](http://developers.google.com/gdata).

There isn't a REST API available (at this time) for Google Docs documents, although there is an "API-like" service provided by [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script), the JavaScript-in-the-cloud solution which provides programmatic access to Google Docs (via its [DocumentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/) object), including [Docs add-ons](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/docs).

To read plain text from a Google Doc, considered **file**-level **access**, you would use the [**Google Drive API**](http://developers.google.com/drive) instead. Examples of using the Drive API:

- Exporting a Google Sheet as CSV ([blog post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/07/exporting-google-sheet--as-csv.html))
- "Poor man's plain text to PDF" converter ([blog post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2015/12/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html)) (*)

(*) - TL;DR: upload plain text file to Drive, import/convert to Google Docs format, then export that Doc as PDF. Post above uses Drive API v2; [this follow-up post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2015/12/migrating-to-new-google-drive-api-v3.html) describes migrating it to Drive API v3, and here's a [developer video](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2016/01/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html) combining both "poor man's converter" posts.

The solution to the OP is to perform similar operations as what you see in both posts above but ensure you're using the `text/plain` export MIMEtype. For other import/export formats to/from Drive, see [this related question SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38406284/305689) as well as the [downloading files from Drive docs page](http://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads). Here's some pseudocode that searches for Google Docs documents called "Hello World" in my Drive folder and displays the contents of the first matching file found on-screen (assuming *DRIVE* is your API service endpoint):

```
from __future__ import print_function

NAME = 'Hello World'
MIME = 'text/plain'

# using Drive API v3; if using v2, change 'pageSize' to 'maxResults',
# 'name=' to 'title=', and ".get('files')" to ".get('items')"
res = DRIVE.files().list(q="name='%s'" % NAME, pageSize=1).execute().get('files')
if res:
    fileID = res[0]['id']  # 1st matching "Hello World" name
    res = DRIVE.files().export(fileId=fileID, mimeType=MIME).execute()
    if res:
        print(res.decode('utf-8')) # decode bytes for Py3; NOP for Py2
```

If you need more than this, see these videos on how to [setup using Google APIs](http://youtu.be/DYAwYxVs2TI?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILOIxBRPPhgYbuSslr50KVq&index=2), [OAuth2 authorization](http://youtu.be/h-gBeC9Y9cE?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILOIxBRPPhgYbuSslr50KVq&index=3), and [creating a Drive service endpoint to list your Drive files](http://youtu.be/Z5G0luBohCg?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILOIxBRPPhgYbuSslr50KVq&index=4), plus a [corresponding blog post for all three](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2014/11/authorized-google-api-access-from-python.html).

To learn more about how to use Google APIs with Python in general, check out [my blog](http://wescpy.blogspot.com) as well as a variety of Google developer videos ([series 1](http://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILOIxBRPPhgYbuSslr50KVq) and [series 2](http://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOU2XLYxmsIJJFx_MVCQJ7eWF3gDxkl)) I'm producing.